# How do I open the workbench in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just started out. When I opened the Eclipse, a dialog box popped up asking for workspace location. I set it in D: drive. Then I closed it and clicked on 'new' in the menu bar- then 'java project'. Then named it 'Dumpargs', kept other settings as default (i.e workspace is still "D:"). But after closing this box by clicking on OK, nothing happens. I cannot see the workbench on left the left side of IDE. Can you tell me what I have done wrong and how can I correct my error?

[Went from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BDYO.png)

[To this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dSMc.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Check right top.. You are in which perspective?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about perspectives yet. I restarted eclipse. I have a blank screen before me right now with just two menu bars on top. Can you tell me what can I do from here? Dumpargs has been created in D:

Comment: Please attach screenshot